# Indirectly assign foreign key in DRF request

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I need to assign `ForeignKey` to object without having it in `Serializer` class. Here's over-simplified version of my case:

I have models called `Company`, `User` and `Order`:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class User(AbstractBaseUser)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', null=False)
    ...

class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', null=False)
    some_other_field = ...
    ...
```

This way there can be several `Companies` and each `Company` can have multiple `users` and `orders`. `User` is allowed to retrieve and create `orders`.

In a `ModelViewSet` that handles `Order` retrieval and creation operations I'm filtering queryset against requesting user:

```
.filter(company=self.request.user.company)
```

This way I can leave `company` field out of `Serializer` class for `Order`:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('some_other_field', ...)
```

Problem arises when user needs to create `order` using `POST` request: `company` field can not be blank, but I don't want to add this field to serializer either because `User` is always assigned to company thus I internally can add this field by checking which user is sending this request.

So far I came up with very brutal solution to override entire `create` method from `CreateModelMixin` and assign fields manually after serializer validation:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    Reservation.objects.create(
        company=self.request.user.company,
        some_other_field=request.data['some_other_field']
    )

    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: you can use serializer.save(company=company)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
serializer.save(company=company)
```

In the viewset, you can customize at the method `perform_create`, with something like

```
serializer.save(company=self.request.user.company)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in you `CreateAPIView`

This can be used to override serializer.save() method and add extra parameters before saving it.

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
    # Do any operatons, and get all the data you need
    serializer.save(    param1 = data1,
                        param2  = data2,
                    )
```

In your case:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    company=self.request.user.company
    serializer.save(company = company)
```